# Animate Text Change of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

**I want to animate text changes in a UILabel.**

For example: old text moves up and new text moves in from the bottom.

I already realised that I would need to labels. One for the old and one for the new text. The second `UILabel` is located below the first. Then both animate up.

However, how do you cut off the first label as it animates past the top portion of the frame?

Comment: Please post any attempt where you tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: By proposing *I can think of a way by having 2 labels* in your question, you lead the answer towards that direction. There is, however, a much shorter and elegant approach leveraging **Core Animation**.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

**Use a`UIView` Extension**

Animate *in place* using a single label:
 - Leverage upon the built-in `CALayer` animations, and a `UIView` extension
 - In the Storyboard, place the `UILabel` inside a `UIView` with *Clip Subviews* flag<sup>†</sup>.
 - `pushTransition` is applicable to most `UIView`

**1. Extension**

```
// Usage: insert view.pushTransition right before changing content
extension UIView {
    func pushTransition(_ duration:CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation:CATransition = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
            kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        animation.type = kCATransitionPush
        animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
        animation.duration = duration
        layer.add(animation, forKey: kCATransitionPush)
    }
}
```

**2. Invocation**

```
if let aLabel = label {
    aLabel.pushTransition(0.4) // Invoke before changing content
    aLabel.text = "\(count)"
    count += 1
}
```

**3. Example**

Animation with a `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut` curve, a `0.4` second duration, and a `kCATransitionFromTop` direction <sup>†</sup>.

[image: CALayer Animation]

---

(†) Clipping is an important step for desired effect.

*Swift 2 and earlier, see [Steve Baughman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008074/steve-baughman)'s comment:*
`self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: kCATransitionPush)`

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-33632266) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-33632266).

Comment: Argh, this no longer works in Swift 3. Will report back when I find a fix.

Comment: Works fine for me in Swift 3. Only have to change one line:
`self.layer.add(animation, forKey: kCATransitionPush)`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with a spring-push animation?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect , what tool did make this gif with? Would you please kindly tell me? I have been searching for a long time.

Comment: @0xfba I've used screengif to great effect. https://github.com/dergachev/screengif

Comment: @AdamWaite: GitHub project maintained to latest Swift

Comment: +1, found link to this answer from GitHub. This actually works really well with other views as well, even with `UITableView`s.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing simple solution. I noticed some unwanted animation flickering when setting the label's text immediately after calling pushTransition(). So I delayed updating the text by 0.01 seconds. Looks like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

**Objective-C**

The *[Swift UIView Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705634/218152)* can be solved in Objective-C with an `Interface Extension`.

**1. The `Interface Extension`**

```
@interface UIView (SO33632266)
- (void)pushTransition:(CFTimeInterval)duration;
@end

@implementation UIView (SO33632266)
// Usage: insert [view pushTransition:]; right before changing content
- (void)pushTransition:(CFTimeInterval)duration
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition new];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    animation.duration = duration;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransitionPush];
}
@end
```

**2. `pushTransition` Invocation**

```
[aLabel pushTransition:0.4];
aLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) ++self.count];
```

**3. In Action**

[image: UILabel animation]

---

**One-off: *without* Interface Extension:**

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
animation.duration = 0.4;
[aLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"kCATransitionPush"];
```

*Invocation:*

```
aLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) ++self.count];
```

Answer (score 3):

QuartzCore provides a [`CATransition`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/catransition) class for animated transition operations. `CATransition` has the following definition:

> The `CATransition` class implements transition animations for a layer. You can specify the transition effect from a set of predefined transitions or by providing a custom `CIFilter` instance.

---

In order to have your label's text transition animated by pushing upwards the old text, you'll have to create an instance of `CATransition` and set its `type` to `kCATransitionPush` and its `subtype` to `kCATransitionFromTop`:

```
let animation = CATransition()
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
animation.type = kCATransitionPush
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
animation.duration = 1
```

You will then be able to animate your label's text transition by adding the animation to your label's layer:

```
label.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
label.text = "Some new content"
```

---

The following Swift 3 Playground code shows a possible implementation in order to animate a `UILabel`'s text transition using `CATransition`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {  
    let label: UILabel = {
        $0.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
        $0.text = "Bob"
        $0.sizeToFit()
        return $0
    }(UILabel())
    let animation: CATransition = {
        $0.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        $0.type = kCATransitionPush
        $0.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
        $0.duration = 1
        return $0
    }(CATransition())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(label)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func toggle(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        label.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        label.text = label.text == "Bob" ? "Dan" : "Bob"
        label.sizeToFit()
    }
}

let controller = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
```